# std::find vs index array for type-tracking

Tags: c++, performance, search, stl

Considering I have a particular class `A` that comes together with some useful strong-typed enum types:

```
/* from A.hpp */
enum class A_type {
    A1,
    A2,
    A3,
    A4,
    /* ... */
    A47
}
static const N_A_type = 47;

class A {
public:
    A();
    /* some other stuff */
};
```

Now consider I have another class that wraps around a vector of `A` pointers and needs to keep track of the type of object in the member container, e.g. for element access and type checking:

```
 class B {
 public:
    B(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& _ptrs, const std::vector<A_type> _types) : ptrs(_ptrs), types(_types) { /**/ };
    /* ... */

    // element acessors w/ const overload
    std::shared_ptr<A>           operator[](const A_type& _type) { /* */ }
    std::shared_ptr<const A> operator[](const A_type& _type) const { /* */ }

    // list types contained in B
    std::vector<A_type> types() const;

    // check if any element of specific A_type exists
    bool    hasType(const A_type& _type) const { /* */ }
    /* ... */
 protected:  
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> ptrs;
};
```

I am looking for an efficient and "clean" method to keep track of which types are present in `B`.  I have though of several ways, but the two that I think are faster and allow for a cleaner syntax are to add a protected/private member of B:

- Use a `vector<A_type>` of the same size as `ptrs` with the correspondent types, and either use `std::find` of manually loop through the vector to check if a particular type is present and return its index. This could imply having to ensure (in the constructor) that both vectors are ordered in order for a faster search;
- Use `vector<int>` of size `N_A_type` (or an `array<int,N_A_type>`) , which would be populated in the constructor and store the index of the correspondent type, if any, and e.g. -1 if not present. Thus accessing/checking a specific type is a matter of casting the enum type to `int` and no vector search is required.

Personally, I prefer the first, as although it is seemingly not as fast/efficient, the interface is cleaner and would allow me e.g. return a subset of `B` using the same constructor and without dragging around a container with a lot of redundant/unnecessary values.

But exactly how much overhead would `std::find` add over the second method?

Comment: Just to clarify, will there be at most only one of each type of object in `B` (limiting it to 47 shared pointers), or can there be multiple pointers for each type in the enum?

Comment: You can use a std::set or a std::multiset with the type of A as key

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yes each key would be unique

Comment: @Nico238 what would be the advantages of using std::set (not familiar with it) over using std::find on an ordered vector?

Comment: - it will take care of the ordering for you (just use insert)
- the search will be O(log(n)), for vector, unless you redo the search algorithm, it will be O(n)

Comment: @Nico238 it still would run imply running a search algorithm though. My question was mostly if there would be performance gain by avoid searching over relatively small (<0) containers of essential integer values.

Comment: Is memory usage an issue?  How many of these `B` objects would you need?  You could just use a `vector` or `array`, indexed by `A_type` (cast to an int).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Not really, and what you suggest is the basis of my second solution. I just don't think it is a very elegant solution and believe that with such small vectors the overhead of using searching algorithms will be negligible.